# Error when inserting data in sparse table SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-insert

I am trying to run an insert query on a SQL wide table (Sparse Table), but I am getting an error:

> "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition"

Query:

```
Insert [dbo].[Table1] (Table1 is a sparse table)
select id, [A],[B], [C], [D], [E] from (
Select  ID, 
            CategoryId, 
            1 as Flag
            From dbo.table2 
       ) a Pivot(Avg(Flag) For CategoryID In (
        [A],
        [B],
        [C],
        [D],
        [E]
           )) As PivotTable
```

I am able to run the query for a normal sql table but it fails for a sparse table. I would really appreciate any help on this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you really have `(Table1 is a sparse table)` in the query? If that's supposed to be a comment, you should put `--` before it, or take it out of the code block entirely.

Comment: The query returns 6 columns. Since you don't specify which columns you want to insert into, it assumes you're trying to insert into all the columns. If there are more than 6 columns, you'll get this error.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a sparse table. Either list the columns you want to fill in, or return enough columns in the query to fill in all of them (you can use `NULL` for the other column values).

Comment: Don't ever use an insert statement without a column list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One of the many benefits SO has over other Q&A sites is that questions can be edited _by anyone_ which means that they can be improved. Your question isn't just valuable to you, it's potentially valuable to other people as well but it's far more valuable if it's clean, concise, well formatted and meets criteria listed in [ask]. marc_s made an edit a while ago which improved your question, but you rolled the edit back, why? - it might not have been entirely "your" question any more, but the essence is the same and the answer(s) will be the same.

Comment: HI @pcdev  - I wasn't aware that other people could edit my question. I thought something was wrong. Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

> - Create an `INSERT` statement that explicitly lists the columns it will insert into - assuming that `ID` might be an `IDENTITY` column
>     that you don't want / can't insert into
> - Define the exact number of values to fill into these columns

your INSERT statement should be something like:

```
insert into table_1 (cola, colb, colc)
       select cola, colb, colc from table_2
```

`insert into tb1 values('1', '2','3')` - this works fine as long you only have 3 columns

if you have 4 columns but only want to insert into 3 of them. 
You have to include column names in `INSERT INTO`

```
   insert into tb1 (Col1,col2,col3) select col1, col2, col3 from tb_2
```

Note: Always explicitly define the list of columns that an `INSERT` statement should fill data into

Comment: _insert into tb1 values('1', '2','3') - this works fine as long you only have 3 columns_ - Note that this also works if you have 4 columns where one is an identity, but I wholeheartedly support explicitly stating the columns, otherwise the insert statement will break if a column is ever added.